# JQuery UI `Slide` Transition Issues With CSS `transform

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, css, angularjs

When executing JQueryUI's `slide` transition on an element with a CSS `transform` the top half of the element is being hidden during the animation.  Is there some way I can adjust my JQueryUI animation and/or CSS to prevent this from happening?

**JSFiddle**: I've created a JSFiddle with the appropriate code - http://jsfiddle.net/9dTkL/4/

To accomplish the vertical centering, I do the following:

```
<style>
#banner-welcome {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
</style>
```

The `top` and `transform` within the CSS allow the banner to fall into the center.

To perform the animation, I execute the following:

```
$('#banner-welcome').toggle(
  'slide',
  function()
  {
    document.location.href = "#/" + destination;
  }
);
```

When the animation starts the top half of the `#welcome-banner` disappears, and the bottom half animates.  I've removed the `transform` from the CSS and everything works great -- except that my banner is no longer centered.

I am performing the vertical centering this way due to a combination of AngularJS and `ng-views`.  I had previously used JavaScript to center the element, but adding the logic to the `$(window).resize()` event caused problems in other `ng-views`.  I needed a way to isolate this to the specific `ng-view`.

Is there something I can adjust with my animation or CSS that would not cause the top half of the banner to disappear?

Comment: Can this be tested anywhere? In a link or a fiddle?

Comment: Updated with JSFiddle.  I should also note that I'm using JQueryUI's `toggle` function to perform this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

toggle is removed as of 1.9: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

so please use animate or slideDown or slideUp method

also the transform property **doesn't** need prefixes

```
#banner-welcome {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%;

    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

have you tried adding **transform-origin** property

```
#banner-welcome {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%;

    transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

im not seeing the top part disappear in latest Firefox 24

Comment: BAM!  I switch my animation call to `animate`, removing my need for JQueryUI and fixing the animation.  I didn't try the `transform-origin` since just updating to `animate` did the trick.  Thank you!